# Angular cli: include angularjs component styles in ngUpgrade hybrid project

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli, ng-upgrade

Now I'm moving to a hybrid angular/angularjs project. But I stuck with import styles problem.

For example, my simple angularJs component:

```
import template from './simple.html';
import controller from './simple.controller.js';

import './simple.less'; // <-- Look at

export const SimpleComponent = {
  template,
  controller
};
```

I expect that styles will be extracted and included in the project.
Before I switched to the angular-CLI all magic works because of '[MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin)'.

If I create angular components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple',
  templateUrl: './simple.html'
  styleUrls: ['./simple.less']
})
```

All styles add correct. The same, if I it with angular.json ->

```
(path) projects.projectName.architect.build.options.styles 
"styles": [ "src/assets/styles/index.less" ]
```

Now I suggest 2 ways to solve the problem (first doesn't work, second will be in a pinch):

1) Add `"extractCss":true` rule in `angular.json -> projects.projectName.architect.serve.options`. But it doesn't work.
I create [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13009) on github about `"extractCss"` option.
But maybe I don't understand what exactly `"extractCss"` option means, and delegate 'MiniCssExtractPlugin' plugin functionality to it?

2) Create 'app.less' in 'src/app' folder and add all component styles to it. After that include it to 'angular.json' -> "styles": ["src/app/app.less"]. But it takes a lot of overhead because we have a lot of components =)

Thank you for attention =)

Comment: Did you installed less?

Comment: Yes i did. The rest of the styles works ok. For ex: global styles in 'angular.json': 

`"styles": [
              "src/assets/styles/index.less",
             "src/assets/styles/vendor.less"
            ].`

And styles in component: 
`@Component ({styleUrls: ['./simple.less']})`